# TextEdit not recognizing Encoding

Tags: iphone, objective-c, utf-8, nsstring

I am writing a string to a file like so:

```
NSString *docsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [docsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.txt", nameOfFile]];

[fileString writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

For some reason, TextEdit doesn't recognize the `NSUTF8StringEncoding`. How can I make sure it does?

Would appreciate some help, Fabian

Comment: You are not showing nameOfFile initialization but assuming that is correct that should work. Go to Terminal and do `cat filename.txt` to see there is real data in the file, and also check preferences of TextEdit maybe file opening encoding, etc are not correct? Also try passing a NSError object instead of NULL maybe there is an error there ;)

Comment: @nacho4d There totally is data in there :) I even checked `xattr -l file.txt` and `com.apple.TextEncoding` is set to `utf-8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just recreated you code and it works fine for me. TextEdit can read the file just fine.

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

  NSString *fileString = @"Blah blah.";
  NSString *nameOfFile = @"blah";
  NSString *docsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
  NSString *path = [docsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.txt", nameOfFile]];
  printf("fileString:\n%s\n", [fileString UTF8String]);
  printf("docsDirectory:\n%s\n", [docsDirectory UTF8String]);
  printf("path:\n%s\n", [path UTF8String]);
  /*
  fileString:
  Blah blah.
  docsDirectory:
  /Users/daniel/Documents
  path:
  /Users/daniel/Documents/blah.txt
  */
  [fileString writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
  [pool release];
  return 0;
}
```

The only thing I can think of is your TextEdit preferences, here are mine:
[image]

Comment: could you put some special characters in your string, such as öäü?